# Write `for(x : y) if(p(x)) return x;` in modern algorithmic form

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, return, c++14

I always try to use STL-like algorithms when possible, as they are concise and very expressive.

I have this code in one of my libraries:

```
auto& findFlag(const std::string& mName)
{
    for(auto& f : makeRangeCastRef<Flag>(getFlags())) 
        if(f.hasName(mName)) 
             return f;

    throw Exception::createFlagNotFound(mName, getNamesStr());
}
```

I  would like to write it in a modern C++ algorithmic form, but I can't figure out how to deal with the early `return` and the possible `throw`.

```
for(auto& value : container) if(predicate(value)) return value; 
//                                                ^~~~~~
// IMPORTANT: return from the caller function, not the algorithm itself
```

Ideally I'd like to write the real code snippet as:

```
auto& findFlag(const std::string& mName)
{
    early_return_if(makeRangeCastRef<Flag>(getFlags()), 
        [&mName](const auto& f){ return f.hasName(mName); });

    throw Exception::createFlagNotFound(mName, getNamesStr());
}
```

Obviously, something like `early_return_if` cannot exist - there is no way, as far as I know, to call `return` on the caller function from a callee. `return early_return_if(...)` could work, but then I can't throw the exception without creating a specific algorithm that throws exceptions.

**What do you suggest? Should the keep the code as it is or is there any algorithm-like way I can re-write it?**

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, `std::find_if` is a good candidate, but there is an unnecessary check that can be avoided:

```
auto& findFlag(const std::string& mName)
{
    auto container(makeRangeCastRef<Flag>(getFlags())); // Need to write this out...

    // Need to keep track of the returned iterator...
    auto it(findIf(container, [&mName](const auto& f){ return f.hasName(mName); }));

    if(it != container.end()) return *it; // I don't like this either...

    throw Exception::createFlagNotFound(mName, getNamesStr());
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good case for [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) out of `<algorithm>`

Comment: `auto it = std::find_if(begin(container), end(container), predicate); return it != end(container) ? *it : throw /*...*/;`

Comment: @T.C., @Cyber: I thought about using `std::find_if`, but the check `it != end(container)` is unnecessary and I wanted to avoid that

Comment: Because comparing two iterators is oh so expensive?

Comment: @T.C.: It obviously isn't. It's not a performance concern - it's just unnecessary and doesn't look "clean". I'd rather use the for-loop.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You have `O(N)` comparisons for finding the element, and you care that in (only) case all of them fail, you will get one extra?

Comment: @luk32: Again, it's not about the performance. I'm trying to use an algorithm that will make the code more readable, concise and expressive - adding an unnecessary check doesn't help

Comment: Agree with luk32, T.C.'s solution looks good to me.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Honestly, if readability is such a big concern, either start going overboard with macros (mold C++ into the language you want) or don't use C++ at all (and pick a language that allows for more syntactic flexibility).

Comment: Stick with the loop, for crying out loud. You're doing your code disservice by forcing algorithms upon it where they're not needed only because they're supposedly "modern" (SGI STL has been around from 1994, IIANM).

Comment: @jrok: I think you're right - I was overthinking this. I'll stick with the loop

Comment: Honestly, I find the `find_if`/`for` versions readable. Maybe it's not the lines-per-functionality you seek, however your preferred options, would probably make me scrach my head a bit, but only because such semantics are (again IHMO) uncommon. You want to jump back two levels or one from `early_return_if`. This kind of violates structural programming. You could implement `early_return_if(container, predicate, exception/failback)` but it would look like `find_if`/`for`.

Comment: The only big advantage of the range or iterator based loop is that it makes is really easy to swap iteration method: write & use `search_if_parallel`, and check that your search condition is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that using the loop is the most expressive and generally best solution for this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

A range-based algorithm that uses `boost::optional`.  `reference_type_t` left as an exercise (hint: write `iterator_type_t` first based off of adl-lookup of `begin` on a range).

```
template<class Range, class Function>
boost::optional< reference_type_t<Range> >
search_if( Range&& r, Function&& f ) {
  for( auto&& x:std::forward<Range>(r) ) {
    if (f(x))
      return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x);
  }
  return {};
}
```

Then:

```
auto& findFlag(const std::string& mName) {
  auto result = search_if(
    makeRangeCastRef<Flag>(getFlags()),
    [&](auto&& f){return f.hasName(mName); }
  );
  if (result) return *result;
  throw Exception::createFlagNotFound(mName, getNamesStr());
}
```

you could do away with the exception entirely, and have `findFlag` return an `optional` itself (which basically makes it `search_if`).

And no, you cannot inject flow control into the function that calls you.

The above does rely on an `optional` that supports optional references.  These are controversial: the upcoming `std::optional` did not support them last I checked.

You can also replace such `optional`s with simple `T*`s.

```
template<class Range, class Function>
value_type_t<Range>*
search_if( Range&& r, Function&& f ) {
  for( auto&& x:std::forward<Range>(r) ) {
    if (f(x))
      return &x;
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

but a downside is that if your range is strange (like `std::vector<bool>`), you'll end up with a reference to a temporary above.

A sketch of `value_type_t` and `reference_type_t`, which take a range/container and output that range/containers value/reference type:

```
namespace adl_aux {
  using std::begin;
  template<class R> using iterator_t = decltype( begin(std::declval<R>()) );
}
using adl_aux iterator_t;
template<class T>struct void{using type=void;}
template<class T>using void_t=typename void<T>::type;

template<class R,class=void>
struct value_type {};
template<class R>
struct value_type<R, void_t< iterator_t<R> > {
  using type = std::iterator_traits< iterator_t<R> >::value_type;
};
template<class R>using value_type_t = typename value_type<R>::type;

template<class R,class=void>
struct reference_type {};
template<class R>
struct reference_type<R, void_t< iterator_t<R> > {
  using type = std::iterator_traits< iterator_t<R> >::reference_type;
};
template<class R>using reference_type_t = typename reference_type<R>::type;
```

it can be made more robust -- the SFINAE check on iterators can check iterator axioms on the return type of `begin`, and ensure that `end` is either an identical iterator or a compatible sentinal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly makeRangeCastRef<>() and some of your other code is doing but personally I think the find_if version is more readable than your original version if you write it more like this:

```
auto& findFlag(const std::string& mName)
{
    auto findIt = find_if(cbegin(getFlags()), cend(getFlags()), [&](const auto& f){ return f.hasName(mName); });
    if (findIt == container.end()) throw Exception::createFlagNotFound(mName, getNamesStr());
    return *findIt;
}
```

It seems more natural to me to check for the exceptional condition (flag not found) and throw an exception, otherwise fall through to the normal exit path of returning the found item, rather than in your loop based version returning from inside the loop in the 'normal' condition, and otherwise falling through to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alexandrescu's [`Expected<T>`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) you can write an algorithm that returns an object convertible to the element you are looking for or throws an exception if it wasn't found. Something like (didn't compile this):

```
template <class It, class Pred, class Else>
Expexted<T&> find_if_ref(It first, It last, Pred pred, Else el)
{
    auto it = find_if(first, last, pred);
    if (it == last) {
        try {
            el();
        }
        catch (...) {
            return std::current_exception();
        }
    }
    return *it;
}
```